Can't set external monitor to native resolution (4K@60hz), but can do in Windows 10
I have Ubuntu 24.04 LTS running on Dell Inspiron 15 i7-1165G7 with Nvidia GeForce MX330. Initially, I had 22.04 LTS, but I upgraded to 23.04 then to 23.10 and then to 24.04 LTS.
I tried the following (gtf doesn't work either):
cvt 3840 2160 60
xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "3840x2160_60.00"

But that did not work, however, this worked:
cvt 2560 1440 30
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_30.00"  146.25  2560 2680 2944 3328  1440 1443 1448 1468 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 2560x1440_30.00

I also tried adding this entry to /etc/default/grub file:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=HDMI-A-1:3840x2160@60"

But that didn't work either even after doing grub-update and rebooting.
All the packages are up-to-date when I do sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
One more thing, I'm using Xorg/X11, not Wayland as even 1440@30hz didn't even work in Wayland.
What could the issue be? Is this something to do with firmware? Or drivers perhaps?
One thing for sure is my hardware and HDMI cable can run 4k@60hz because it's working fine when I boot into windows 10.

Try a cvt command wth the -r parameter: cvt -r 3840 2160 60 which the man page says: Create  a  mode with reduced blanking.  This allows for higher frequency signals, with a lower or equal dotclock.

@codlord Thank you for your comment. Sadly, that did not work either. Apparently, I cannot even get 60Hz on 1440p either.
